# How to capture the value in array in javascript and return the value in Yii2 controller?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

> I am trying to generate multiple barcode at a time and save the generated barcode numbers in my database . Still now i have generated
>   multiple barcode but i had a problem while saving it to database .

**My code till now :-**

```
   function getbarcode(num,barcode)
  {

    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
     var barcodenum = parseInt(barcode)+parseInt(i);
     var patron= barcodenum.toString();  
     var type = "code11";
     var settings = {
      barWidth: 2,
      barHeight: 50,
      moduleSize: 5,
      addQuietZone: true,
      marginHRI: 5,
      bgColor: "#FFFFFF",
      color: "#000000",
      fontSize: 10,
      output: "css",
      posX: 0,
      posY: 0,
      fontOptions: "bold",
    };
    $('#barcoderesult').append('<div id="showBarcode'+ i +'" 
    style="float:left" />');
    $("#showBarcode"+i).barcode(patron, type, settings); 
    $("#showbarcode"+i).animate({height: "100%", width: "100%"}); 

  }
}
```

> Now in my variable patron , it contains multiple generated barcode number . Now i need to push the barcode number in patron to an array and pass the array in yii2 controller through ajax ? How can i do it ? I didnt  have any idea .

Comment: In this **getbarcode()** only, you wanted to use AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create one array namely, `array_barcode` and use [JavaScript Array push() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) to fill values into this array. Then, after for loop, pass this array values to controller through AJAX if it's not empty.

```
<script>
function getbarcode(num, barcode){

  var array_barcode = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    var barcodenum = parseInt(barcode) + parseInt(i);
    var patron = barcodenum.toString();
    array_barcode.push(patron); //Push generated barcode into array 'array_barcode'

    var type = "code11";
    var settings = {
      barWidth: 2,
      barHeight: 50,
      moduleSize: 5,
      addQuietZone: true,
      marginHRI: 5,
      bgColor: "#FFFFFF",
      color: "#000000",
      fontSize: 10,
      output: "css",
      posX: 0,
      posY: 0,
      fontOptions: "bold",
    };
    $('#barcoderesult').append('<div id="showBarcode' + i + '"style = "float:left" / > ');
    $("#showBarcode" + i).barcode(patron, type, settings);
    $("#showbarcode" + i).animate({height: "100%", width: "100%"});
  }

  if(array_barcode.length > 0){//If array is not empty
    $.ajax({
      //url: "/controller-name/controller-action-name",
      url: "/MyController/my-action",
      type: "POST",
      data: {array_barcode : array_barcode},
      success: function (data) {
        alert("Success");
      },
      error: function () {
        alert("Error Ocurred");
      },
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

**Controller**

Since, not much information was provided. So, I assumed controller name as `MyController` and action name as `MyAction`. Now, in action `MyAction`, check whether request coming is of AJAX type or not. Otherwise, throw error. Retrieve array values through `Yii::$app->request->post()`.

```
<?php

class MyController
{

  .
  .
  .
  public function actionMyAction(){

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {

      $array_barcode = Yii::$app->request->post('array_barcode');
      foreach($array_barcode as $barcode){

        /*
         * Your Logic
         * Save '$barcode' to database
         */

      }


    }
    throw new ForbiddenHttpException("Problem Ocurred");

  }
}
?>
```